# Add column to CSV with formatting

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a small csv with 3 columns.

```
Date        Time    Event
12/19/2021  9:00am  Low
12/19/2021  7:30am  Medium
12/20/2021  9:00am  Low
```

I want to add a 4th column with header of Warning.  In the 4th column I want to subtract 15 minutes from column

```
Date        Time    Event   Warning
12/19/2021  9:00am  Low     8:45am
12/19/2021  7:30am  Medium  7:15am
12/20/2021  9:00am  Low     8:45am
```

Im having difficulty with the formatting?.

Thank you for your time today.

Comment: What would happen if _Time_ was `12:14AM` (for your testing `([datetime]'12:14:00AM').AddMinutes(-15)`) ? See, having a column that is not associated to a _Date_ is a problem.

Comment: yeah that is where Im getting confused.

Comment: Yeah, we can't decide that for you, you need to tell us what should happen when the condition I mentioned above is met.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the string to datetime?  So if above condition is met the result would be 11:59:00PM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property on `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to calculate the time difference, however this would leave the *Date* column intact.

```
# Use $Csv = Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv here instead
$csv = @'
Date        Time    Event
12/19/2021  9:00am  Low
12/19/2021  7:30am  Medium
12/20/2021  9:00am  Low
'@ -replace ' +',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv | Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'Warning'
    Expression = {
        ([datetime]$_.Time).AddMinutes(-15).ToShortTimeString()
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Date       Time   Event  Warning
----       ----   -----  -------
12/19/2021 9:00am Low    8:45 AM
12/19/2021 7:30am Medium 7:15 AM
12/20/2021 9:00am Low    8:45 AM
```

Comment: The date column intact is ok.  I don't forsee any times where date would change.  I appreciate your time Santiago.  This is helpful.